# what is libcpmtd.lib for?

Tags: c++, build, lib

All of a sudden, my program got link errors like below:

libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2038: 'RuntimeLibrary' unmatched.The value 'MTd_StaticDebug' is different from that of [project x], which is: 'MDd_DynamicDebug'

Since this error suddenly appeared on multiple computers, I believe this was not caused by unintended modification of any file.

Version: Visual Studio 2013

### Question-1:

Could you give any hint about the reason of this error and how to solve it?

---

What I did:
I remove the libcpmtd.lib from the import library list of project setting, then the build error disappeared and everything was OK.

But, I am not sure what libcpmtd.lib is for?
Google told me there is CRT inside, but what are the content specifically?

Perhaps this library was added and then not relevant from some point of time.

### Question-2:

what is in side libcpmtd.lib? I want to figure out what I might have lost after I removed the lib.

Comment: Just put everything to static link. We have plenty of disk space nowadays.

Comment: thanks Michael, but there are about 100 project in my solution, using static link will increase size and affect the time that user pull latest version from server.

Comment: since this problem suddently arose on multiple PCs, I am not suspecting a wrong config value.
instead, I would try something like vcpkg later. for memo now:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2038?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

These are the C++ standard runtime libraries. With Visual C++, you have 2 options, which give you 4 permutations of the library it links to.

### Debug v.s. Release

As it suggests, do you want the C++ runtime lib that has additional error checking?

### Static v.s. Dynamic

If you happen to be compiling only a simple exe, then linking to the library statically should be fine. If however you have a large project consisting of multiple DLL's, then it makes sense to load the CRT dynamically *(so it can be shared between the DLL's, rather than being duplicated into each one)*.

So what you have is a mis-configured build. You'll need to check the **C/C++ Runtime Library** settings for each library, DLL, and exe within your project *(which you can find in your project settings, under C/C++ -> Code Generation)*.

You will need to make sure that each one links to the same runtime library (i.e. Debug DLL for all debug settings, Release DLL for all release settings).

If that doesn't fix it, then there are two other possible causes:

1. You have started linking to a 3rd party library, and that's the cause of the CRT mis-match. Most libs ship debug and release builds for this reason, so hopefully you'll just need to update the libs you are linking to.
2. You are inadvertently pulling in a Debug lib into a release build (or a release build lib, into a debug exe). For this you will need to check all of the additional library directories, and/or check to make sure all of the debug & release output directories are correct *(i.e. you aren't accidentally compiling a debug lib into a release build folder)*.

Comment: robthebloke, thank you for your detailed explanation. right or wrong, I solved my problem as described in my own answer.